# need to overwrite specific line at config file with bash

Tags: bash

I need to overwrite specific line at config file.
No print/echo, else just overwrite at the file.

For example I have file:

```
$ echo test.file
$ line1
$ line2
$ line3
$ line4
```

I want to overwrite line 2 to be line7090:

```
$ echo test.file
$ line1
$ line7090
$ line3
$ line4
```

Thank's in help,
Alex

Comment: By line number or by line contents? In first case, use `head -1 test.file && echo line7090 && tail -2 test.file`. In second case, use `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` option `-i`

```
sed -i '2s/^.*$/line7090/' file
```

or, without to use regex

```
sed -i -n '2!p;2iline7090' file
```

or `gawk` option `-i inplace`

```
awk -i inplace 'NR==2{print "line7090"; next}1' file
```

you get in `file`:

```
line1
line7090
line3
line4
```

Comment: Gnu awk needs to be version 4.1.0 or above.